Way of keeping multiple almost identical reports maintained in Power BI?
I have created Power BI Dashboards illustrating sales and sales commission data for my company. All of the data is already merged and stored in a SQL Server table called SalesCommission.
There is a master dashboard as well as an individual dashboard for each sales person at our company. All of the individual dashboards are identical in every way except the SQL query. For SalesPerson A it would be
select * 
from SalesCommission 
where SalesPerson = 'SalesPerson A'

Besides that all of the visualizations and everything is the same. Employees need to be able to view their data but not have the ability to see anyone else's.
My issue is that now when I make a change I have to go to every individual dashboard and make the same change which sucks with how many sales people I have to do it for.
Can anyone think of a better process where I just have to make the change once and it will be reflected on every individual dashboard?
I currently will just copy and paste the file to each new person and change the queries, it is just a hassle

Are you confusing reports and dashboards?
In Power BI Desktop, you can create a report with a query that includes all sales people. Add a slicer for sales people to the report. Publish the report to the cloud service.
In the cloud service, use the slicer in the report to filter the data to one sales person. Create a dashboard and pin the report visuals to the dashboard. Share the dashboard with the respective sales person. Create a separate dashboard for each sales person.
When you need up update the report, any pinned visuals in the dashboard will inherit the updates from the report. The pinned dashboard visuals will retain any filter/slicer settings used a the time the visual was pinned.
Another approach that doesn't require creating separate dashboards for each Sales person is to configure Row Level Security. Then you only have to set up one report, share it with the sales people and they all only see their own data based on their role.

Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI can be used to restrict data
access for given users. Filters restrict data access at the row level,
and you can define filters within roles.

For more info on Row Level Security, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls

Teylyn, Thank you. Row Level Security was exactly what I needed
